# TypeScript with Lodash: _.map(["123", " 234 "], _.trim) returns boolean[]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

I have an array of strings which have been split like so:

```
var searchValue = "600-800, 123, 180";
var groups = searchValue.split(","); // => ["600-800", " 123", " 180"]
```

(so there is potentially whitespace around the items) and I would like to remove the whitespace. I know that I can use `Array.prototype.map` with `String.prototype.trim`, but I would like a solution specifically using Lodash.

[According to the docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#trim), I should be able to say: `_.map(['  foo  ', '  bar  '], _.trim);` and it will return `['foo', 'bar']`, which is a `string[]`.

However, TypeScript is barking at me. Here's what I'm seeing in my editor.

[image]
[image]

I am running TypeScript 2.3.2 and Lodash 4.17.4

Strangely enough, if I say:

`var values:string[] = _.map(['  foo  ', '  bar  '], String.prototype.trim);`

The TypeScript errors go away, but I get the following runtime error when `searchValue` is empty, and `groups` returns `[""]`:

> TypeError: String.prototype.trim called on null or undefined

### Things I have tried:

```
var values:string[] = _.map(_.filter(groups, group => group.indexOf("-") === -1), _.trim);
var values:string[] = _.map(_.filter(groups, function (group) { return group.indexOf("-") === -1; }), _.trim);
var values:string[] = _.map<string, (string?: string, chars?: string) => string>(_.filter(groups, function (group) { return group.indexOf("-") === -1 }), _.trim);
var values:string[] = _.map<string, (string?: string, chars?: string) => string[]>(_.filter(groups, function (group) { return group.indexOf("-") === -1 }), _.trim);
var values:string[] = _.map<string, (string: string, chars: string) => string>(_.filter(groups, function (group) { return group.indexOf("-") === -1 }), _.trim);
var values:string[] = _.map<string, (string: string) => string>(_.filter(groups, function (group) { return group.indexOf("-") === -1 }), _.trim);
```

All to no avail. I am at a loss. Is there something I am doing wrong here or is this possibly a Lodash/TypeScript bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following variation seems to work:

```
let values: string[] = _.map(['  foo  ', '  bar  '], str => _.trim(str))
```

Here's my guess as to why this is happening. There are many overloads for `map`, and you want to target this one:

```
map<T, TResult>(
    collection: List<T> | null | undefined,
    iteratee: ListIterator<T, TResult>
): TResult[];
```

where `ListIterator` is defined as:

```
type ListIterator<T, TResult> = (value: T, index: number, collection: List<T>) => TResult;
```

Thus you want the trimming function to match the above definition for `ListIterator`. But `trim` is actually defined as:

```
trim(
    string?: string,
    chars?: string
): string;
```

So when you do the following:

```
let values: string[] = _.map(['  foo  ', '  bar  '], _.trim);
```

You actually end up hitting a different overload, which is defined as:

```
    map<T, TObject extends {}>(
        collection: List<T>|Dictionary<T>|NumericDictionary<T> | null | undefined,
        iteratee?: TObject
    ): boolean[];
```

So when you switch to the following variation:

```
let values: string[] = _.map(['  foo  ', '  bar  '], str => _.trim(str))
```

Your trimming function `str => _trim(str)` conforms to `ListIterator`, even though it leaves out the last 2 parameters (`index` and `collection`).

Comment: Great explanation, this makes sense. i will Try it first thing Monday morning and mark as accepted if it ends up working for me. Still curious as to why the docs give the example they give. Seems strange, doesn't it?

Comment: The example they give works in plain JavaScript. But type definitions were added afterwards to help when using TypeScript, so sometimes you have to be more specific. Notice the first parameter of `trim` is defined as `string`, while the first parameter of `ListIterator` is defined as the generic type `T`, which in your case is a `string` since you have a `string` array. So if you run their example in plain dynamic JavaScript, it works because only the first parameters are used. But you have to be more specific when using TypeScript because it's checking all of the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `_.trim` can take two arguments:

```
trim(string?: string, chars?: string): string;
```

Which is incompatible with lodash's `ListIterator` type, in which the second argument, if present, is a number (the index).

Thus the compiler is falling back to a different typing for the `_.map` function, an obscure one which takes an object as the iteratee and returns an array of booleans ("returns true for elements that the properties of the given object, else false.")

Frank Modica's answer gives the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this was helpful. Makes me wonder why the docs give the example they give, though - seems strange, doesn't it?