# TypeScript complains about returning boolean when it's object

Tags: typescript

There is a `createFields` function like this

`map` is from lodash

```
const createFields = (usecase: SchemaObject): FieldInterface[] => {
  // TODO: Make the form blueprint to be generated from json schema

  const properties = usecase.properties;
  const requiredProperties = usecase.required || [];

  if (properties && isSchemaObject(properties)) {
    return map(
      properties,
      (value: SchemaObject, key: string): FieldInterface => {
        return {
          type: value.type,
          name: key,
          label: key,
          readonly: false,
          required: requiredProperties.includes(key),
          validations: [],
        };
      },
    );
  }
  return [];
};
```

As you can see in the image, typescript reports error on the return value of the `map` function and return value of the iteratee.

[image]

But the return value is an object as you can see in the code. And if I change the return type of the iteratee to `boolean`, it complains the other way around, like this.

[image]

What's the problem here? How is `boolean` being returned at all?

Comment: You **import { map } from 'lodash';** , right?

Comment: @PhatHuynh yes, i did.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to lodash `map` function overload.

[TypeScript with Lodash: _.map(["123", " 234 "], _.trim) returns boolean[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467778/typescript-with-lodash-map123-234-trim-returns-boolean)

So either need to put it with correct overload.

Or replacing lodash `map` with native `Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => {})`.